# Electronics Books

Tags: transistors, operational-amplifier, mosfet, jfet

I am earching for a good book for electronic devices and circuits. Details about 'dc' as well as 'ac' biasing are what I am interested in. If you could guide me to a good book, it would be wonderful. Biasing should be considered in detail.

Comment: Your first sentence is very broad, the second ('biasing') seems very restricted. Maybe you should give more background about your current level and where you want to go. Lacking further information, my best recommendation is the bible of electronics: [H&H](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Electronics).

Comment: Although it's aimed more towards Ham Operators, the [ARRL Handbook](http://www.arrl.org/shop/ARRL-Handbook-2013-Hardcover-Edition) covers a wide range or electronic principles including biasing.

Comment: If you click "Questions" right under the "Electrical Engineering" at the top of the page and then select the "Frequent" tab, the second question "Basic Electronics Book" should provide a number of fine answers.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend "The Art of Electronics" by Horowitz & Hill. It's a bit dated in places, but there is no better book that will give you a good understanding with just the right amount of math.